# Printing to non default printer from c#

Tags: c#, printing

I need to be able to print out a number of documents aytomatically with no user input.

The application is going to sit on a server and print at a certain point each day. I have the requirement to print some documents to 1 printer and some to another printer.

I cannot get my code to print to the non default printer, unless that non-default printer is the Microsoft XPS Document writer, which leads me to suspect permissions.

I am setting the printer with `PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "*printername*"` but get a printerexception error saying the settings are incorrect.

I did find an article that metioned a similer error but this was with ASP.Net and not C# - it was to do with Windows Impersonation but I really dont understand what to do to get it working in c#.

I should add that I know the network printer name is correct as I got a little bit of MS Code to show all installed printers and copied the name from the list it provided.

Comment: I think it would help if you post the actual code that you are using to do the printing. I have done this type of application before and it is pretty straightforward. Permissions could be an issue and be sure the user under which the application is running actually has the printers installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the default-printer you can do it by the winapi with:

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);
```

If you want to reset the defaultprinter after your code is finished you probably need another method from the winapi:

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetDefaultPrinter(StringBuilder pszBuffer, ref int size);
```

A list of all available printers you can get by:

```
List<string> printers = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that if I print to \servername\printername it works, as opposed to printing to the name of the printer as it shows in control panel. I now have a different issue - if I print to the default printer i.e. dont specift a printer, then it spits them out quickly. If I specify a printer it waits for about a minute then prints, then waits a minute then prints the next one etc - why should it take longer this way?

Comment: You should post your different issue as a new question.

Comment: Yep...This really is a different question.